# Proof help; binomial coefficients

Tags: proof-writing, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I'm stuck on this and am not sure about the right way to proceed; what I did ended up being entirely wrong so I won't post it -at the time, our professor touched on it and it was entirely different from what I did. I really want to know how to correctly do this problem and I am not able to receive relevant help on it now outside of this site so I would be very appreciative of insight.

Prove that

$$(n+1)\mid{{2n}\choose{n}}$$ for every $n \in\mathbb N$.

There was a suggestion to write the quotient as a difference of binomial coefficients.

Thanks

Comment: It is probably best to write what you've attempted, so that we know where to help you out :)

Comment: I've never touched this code before and am new, please excuse the misformatting

Comment: Hint:  $\binom {2n}n=\frac {n+1} n\times \binom {2n}{n+1}$

Comment: @KubitaAtibuk Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Following the hint, notice that
$$\binom{2n}{n} - \binom{2n}{n+1} = \frac{1}{n+1} \binom{2n}{n}$$
This follows from
$$\binom{2n}{n+1} = \frac{n}{n+1} \binom{2n}{n}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\binom{2n}n=\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)\cdot\ldots\cdot2n}{n!} \ldots$$

So your problem in fact is to prove that $\;n!\,\mid\,(n+2)\cdot\ldots\cdot2n\;$ and you can try, say, induction here. And it is a pretty beautiful and interesting little exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Note that:

$${{2n}\choose{n}}=\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}= 2^n \frac{ 1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdots (2n-1)}{n!}$$

Indeed multiplying both sides by $(n!)^2$

$$(2n)!=2^n\cdot 1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots (2n-1)\cdot n!=\\1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots (2n-1)\cdot 2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdots 2n=1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdots (2n-1)(2n)=(2n)!$$